# How casting works in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to understand how object casting works in Java Internally.

Here is my small code example

```
public interface Processor {

}


public class Mainclass {

    Object getObject(){

        return new Object();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){


        Mainclass ob = new Mainclass();
        Processor prcsr = (Processor) ob.getObject();
   }
}
```

When `ob.getObject()` gets called, It returns an `Object` reference type which is holding a location of `Object` class instance. Correct ?

So when we cast `Object` reference type to `Processor`, What is happening actually ? Does it converts `Object` reference type to processor type which will be holding to `Object` class Instance location?

If yes, then Processor is a Interface here, then who is Implementing this Interface here ?

I'm confused here, Can anyone help me how it works internally ?

Thanks

Comment: That code should raise a `ClassCastException`, since an instance of `Object` is not an instance of `Processor`.

Comment: Nothing happens, other than Java checks if the thing being cast is an instance of the thing you are casting too. Casting is just a way of telling the compiler you know more than it does (in this case, you're wrong though).

Comment: Casting directly is the programmer telling the compiler, "No, seriously! It's a Processor" and the complier says, "Okay, you're the boss"... and then the runtime treats your object like a Processor and says: "Complier, you're drunk, go home and take this exception with you!" And then the programmer gets that exception and rethinks his life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it converts `Object` reference type to `Processor` type which will be holding to `Object` class Instance location?

No, because `Object` does not implement the interface `Processor`. Also because of this, the cast will fail, throwing a `ClassCastException`.

Casting a type (`Object`) to another unrelated type (`Processor`) will generally fail.

> What is happening actually?

Casting is you telling the compiler what type a variable should actually be, because you know better than than the compiler.

Here

```
Processor prcsr = (Processor) ob.getObject();
```

You are telling the compiler

> Hey compiler, you only know that `obj.getObject` returns something of type `Object`, but I know better than you. I know that `obj.getObject` is going to return a type that implements `Processor`.

The compiler hears this and goes "okay", and lets you assign it to the variable `prcsr`, which is of type `Processor`.

However, at runtime, it turns out that `obj.getObject` returned an instance of `Object`, which does not implement `Processor`, so what you were telling the compiler was wrong, and an exception gets thrown.

Now let's say `obj.getObject` actually returns an instance of `FooProcessor`, which does implement `Processor` (declaration not shown here):

```
Object getObject(){

    return new FooProcessor();
}
```

Now at runtime, the cast succeeds because what you were telling the compiler was correct.

So basically, casting is mostly a compile time thing. Very little actually happens at runtime. At runtime it just checks whether what you were saying was right or not. If is wrong, throw an exception.